# Find if a word from column A contains in column B then answers to say as Yes else No

Tags: excel

First off of all, I'm not that advanced of an Excel user. I'm certain Excel can do what I'm about to ask, but I've yet to find a way in any of my attempts or searches.

My question is to Find if a word from column A contains in column B then answers to say as Yes else No

Basically, I have 2 columns. Column A contains Names (e.g. A1: KING GEORGE, A2: BILLY BOWDEN, A3: RESSE DEAN) with 1000 ROWS. Column B contains Names (e.g. B1: GEORGE STEIN, B2: DAVID WIDER, B3: RESSE) (500 rows).

I want to search to see if any of the values in column B are contained within any of the values of Column A. If they are, I want to return the value TRUE in column C.

Comment: Is George Stein a match for King George ?

Comment: Is Resse a match for Resse Dean ?

Comment: Yes, Resse should match for Resse dean and George Stein should match against King George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The formula for this is long, so please copy and paste.

Let's assume that your data start in cells A1 and B1.

Enter this formula in cell C1:

```
=IF(LEN(B1),MAX(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(LEFT(B1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",B1)-1,99)),$A$1:$A$100)),0),IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(MID(B1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",B1)+1,1),99),$A$1:$A$100)),0))>0,FALSE)
```

...and then copy downward as far as needed.

Note: if your data extend below row 100, then you will need to change the two occurrences of this:

```
$A$1:$A$100
```

...so that the `100` is a number large enough for your deepest row.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and update. It looks working now. Will post you if anything needed. Appreciated for your time and kind help.